# Invariance of Yoneda product

Tags: homological-algebra, hochschild-cohomology

Are Yoneda products (also known as cup  product)
on Hochschild cohomology of two quasi-isomorphic DGAs equivalent?

Comment: Yes, cup products and more generally the Tamarki--Tsygan calculus of an algebra is derived invariant, and quasi isomorphic dga algebras are derived equivalent. The first is a recent result of Marco Armenta and Bernhard Keller.